# Codeigniter - value in subquery being ignored

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Not sure where I'm going wrong with my query, but the value dateread is being ignored and am getting an

> error Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$dateread.

```
SELECT `id`.`id`, `id`.`name`, `id`.`deleted`, `id`.`filepath`, `id`.`createddate`, (SELECT createddate as dateread FROM documents_users iu WHERE id.id = iu.docs_id AND iu.users_id = 2346)
FROM (`documents` AS id)
JOIN `documents_years` AS iy ON `id`.`id` = `iy`.`docs_id`
```

Can anyone help?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your query as and then fetch the value of `$dateread` you need to define `dateread` after completion of your sub_query and not within sub_query else it'll be as 
`(SELECT createddate FROM documents_users iu WHERE id.id = iu.docs_id AND iu.users_id = 2346)`

```
SELECT `id`.`id`, `id`.`name`, `id`.`deleted`, `id`.`filepath`, `id`.`createddate`,
(SELECT createddate FROM documents_users iu WHERE id.id = iu.docs_id AND iu.users_id = 2346) as dateread
FROM (`documents` AS id)
JOIN `documents_years` AS iy ON `id`.`id` = `iy`.`docs_id`
```